# Back up my Photos library from Recovery Mode in macOS Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, recovery, data-recovery

My 2012 MacBook Pro will not boot up properly. I decided to start it up in Recovery Mode, using Command-R. There, I can access **Disk Utility**, **Time Machine** and **Reinstall macOS**, and Seek Help Online. Being the idiot that I am, I did not back up my important data on Time Machine or on an external hard drive.

I managed to save my important stuff onto Dropbox by using Safari in "seek help online". However, I would really like to keep my Photos from the Photos app, but these seem impossible to move anywhere, mainly because it is a .photoslibrary file.

Does anybody know a way to do this, for example opening Finder from Terminal, which I cannot seem to manage to do?

Answer (score 1):

.photoslibrary is actually a package (i.e. a folder) which is why Dropbox has difficulty uploading it in one go. Instead, try zipping it first in Terminal using the following:

```
zip -r /path/to/zippedphotos.zip /path/to/yourlibrary.photoslibrary
```